# FirefoxでのJavascriptによるGamepadAPIを使ったXBOX360コントローラー

Tags: javascript, firefox, coffeescript

現在、Javascriptによるゲームフレームワークを作成しています。
主要なブラウザのうち、ChromeとFirefoxへの対応を行っていたのですが、ファミコンのようなUSBゲームパッドと、XBOX360用のUSBゲームコントローラーに対応していました。
しかし、最近のFirefoxではXBOX360コントローラーの値が取れなくなりました（Chromeでは問題ありません）。
値の取り方は以下のコードになります（CoffeeScriptです）。

```
gamepadsinfo = if (navigator.getGamepads) then navigator.getGamepads() else (if (navigator.webkitGetGamepads) then navigator.webkitGetGamepads else [])
```

ネットをいろいろと検索したのですが、みなさん問題なく使えているのか、はたまたXBOX360コントローラーにはあまり関心が無いのかわかりませんが、情報がほとんどありません。

FirefoxでのXBOX360コントローラーの値を、Javascriptから取得する方法はありますでしょうか？
もしくは私がなにか間違っているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox は、 `gamepadisconnected` イベントを取ることを推奨しているようですので、ゲームのメインループ内で上記をしないのなら、以下のコードで取得を試みるべきです。（私の環境でも、１度目の getGamePads() の呼び出しは失敗することがありました。 )

```
window.addEventListener("gamepadconnected", function(e) {
  var gp = navigator.getGamepads()[e.gamepad.index];
  console.log("gamepad[%s]: button.length=%d", gp.id, gp.buttons.length);
});
```

...が! 今度は Chrome が `gamepadisconnected` イベントを持たないため、おかしなことになるので、Chrome 用には、定期的なポーリングをするのがよいようです。

```
var interval;

if (!('ongamepadconnected' in window)) {
  // No gamepad events available, poll instead.
  interval = setInterval(pollGamepads, 500);
}

function pollGamepads() {
  var gamepads = (typeof navigator.getGamepads === "function") ? navigator.getGamepads() : ((typeof navigator.webkitGetGamepads === "function")? navigator.webkitGetGamepads : []);
  for (var i = 0; i < gamepads.length; i++) {
    var gp = gamepads[i];
    if (gp) {
      gamepadInfo.innerHTML = "Gamepad connected at index " + gp.index + ": " + gp.id +
        ". It has " + gp.buttons.length + " buttons and " + gp.axes.length + " axes.";
      gameLoop();
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }
}
```

以上は、Mozilla の [Using the Gamepad API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/Gamepad) を参考にしました。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
gamepadconnectedも試したのですが、FirefoxだとどうにもこうにもXBOX360コントローラーだけまったく反応が無いので、ちょっとドライバーのほうを疑って、XBOX360コントローラー用ドライバーをバージョンダウンしてみたところ、無事にFirefoxでもXBOX360コントローラーが使えるようになりました。